# how to read required file in shell script

Tags: shell, hadoop, mapreduce, streaming

Sorry about the question was unclear, I'm a newbie in Hadoop study.
I edited the question again.

I wrote two Hadoop MapReduce programs in Python: map.py and red.py.
Then wrote the run.sh on HDFS to proceed MapReduce that use Hadoop streaming.

I need read data of half a year on HDFS, files named:20170101-20170630.

Files' path in HDFS:

```
/user/name/20161231
/user/name/20170101
/user/name/20170102
.....
/user/name/20170630
/user/name/20170701
```

How can write the run.sh to read required file?

The part of script in run.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash 
HPHOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH
JAR_PACKAGE=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar
#it dosen't work, how to read selected file:20170101-20170630
IN_PATH=/user/name/20170[101-630] 
OUT_PATH=/user/out
MAP_FILE=/home/map.py
RED_FILE=/home/red.py
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: removed the "python" tag, it's a bash question not a python one.

Comment: How about move or copy the files you want into a single directory at first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure , whether you are trying to read `local` files or `hdfs` files. But will propose both the solutions.

Read 6 months files from local unix system.

```
local_files=`ls /user/name/2017[0][1-6][0-9][0-9]`
for IN_PATH in `echo $local_files`;
do 
   echo "LOCAL FILE IS: $IN_PATH"
done
```

Read 6 months files from hdfs system.

```
hdfs_files=`hdfs dfs -ls /user/hduser/|grep /user/hduser/2016[0][1]|awk '{print $8}'`
for IN_PATH in `echo $hdfs_files`;
do 
  echo "HDFS FILE IS: $IN_PATH"
done
```

Comment: It works. I'm sorry about the question is unclear, I edited it. Thank you very much! :)